# How to use the Ideone api in node.js

Tags: node.js, soap

I am trying to build an online compiler using the Ideone api. I figured out that we need a soap module to create a client for the Ideone api web service. I tried using the soap module. But now I am not actually able to call the client function correctly probably. the function expects 7 parameters. However in node, I am making the function call in this way:

```
var url = "http://ideone.com/api/1/service.wsdl";
var code = req.body.code;
var args = {
user: 'nguria', 
pass: '***',
sourceCode: code,
language: 1,
input: '',
run: true,
pvt: false
}

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
client.createSubmission(args, function(err, result) {
console.log(args);
console.log(result);
});
});
```

However, I am not getting expected returned values in result. Instead I am getting the following output:

```
{ return:
{ attributes: { 'xsi:type': 'ns2:Map' },
item: { key: [Object], value: [Object] } } }
```

Anyone who has worked with the Ideone api in nodejs or any tips ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`console.log(result);`

use

`console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); //to view complete output`

And to access result use

`console.log(result.return.item\[1].value);`

[So Code It](http://socodeit.com)